# Haskell, convert an image to matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix

I try to take an Image PixelRGB8 and convert it to matrix, to do some convolutions on the matrix. For the first try I want to convert it to matrix and convert the matrix back to an image.

I receive this error:

```
    • No instance for (Element Word8)
        arising from a use of ‘matrixToImg’
    • In the expression: matrixToImg $ imgToMatrix img
      In an equation for ‘convImg’:
          convImg img = matrixToImg $ imgToMatrix img
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

what does it mean?

This is the code.

```
import Codec.Picture
import Data.Matrix
import Data.Vector
import Data.Vector.Storable

import Debug.Trace
import GHC.Word

import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
convImg ::Image PixelRGB8 -> Image PixelRGB8
convImg img = matrixToImg $  imgToMatrix img

imgToMatrix ::Image PixelRGB8->Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Matrix Word8
imgToMatrix Image { imageWidth = w, imageHeight = h, imageData = vec } =  ((3*w)><h)  ( Data.Vector.Storable.toList vec)

matrixToImg::Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Matrix Word8->  Image PixelRGB8
matrixToImg matrix = Image  (rows matrix `quot` 3) (cols matrix) (vectorToStorableVector (Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data.flatten(matrix)))
    where vectorToStorableVector vec= Data.Vector.Storable.fromList $ Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data.toList vec
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the exact code that reproduces your error.

Comment: I added the imports. This code reproduces the error

Comment: The types that have `Element` instances are `Float` `Double`, `Complex Float` and `Complex Double`. That is, you can't do this with `Word8`.   If e.g. I put in  Float instead, this compiles fine http://sprunge.us/WTIK

Comment: No it doesn't reproduce the error, though it does give a similar one.

Comment: @Michael , My img is Image PixelRGB8,I know that is function convertRGB8, their is also a way to readImage and than convertRGBF ?

Thanks

Comment: @Alon what I said was a mistake, integral types are represented by the `Z` (`Int64`) type. (There is also the complicated `Mod` business.) So this works, for example http://sprunge.us/hYgj The matrices are holding `Int64`s so you need to make sure that the manipulations respect the fact that 'morally' they are `Word8`

Comment: Thanks this solve my problem, can You write this ad an answer that I can set this question as solved?
Thanks!!

Comment: Or you can use a more special-purpose library such as `friday`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hmatrix` has a limited number of instances for `Element`, and `Word8` isn't one of them. The simple `Integral` type it uses is `type Z = Int64`. If you keep in mind that for you what a `Matrix Int64` holds are morally `Word8`s, some conversion like the following is possible. (It is the same as what you wrote just putting `fromIntegral` in a few places.)

```
import Codec.Picture
import Data.Vector
import Data.Vector.Storable

import Debug.Trace
import GHC.Word

import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

convImg ::Image PixelRGB8 -> Image PixelRGB8
convImg img = matrixToImg $  imgToMatrix img

imgToMatrix ::Image PixelRGB8 -> Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Matrix Z
imgToMatrix Image { imageWidth = w, imageHeight = h, imageData = vec } =  ((3*w)><h)  ( Data.Vector.Storable.toList $ (Data.Vector.Storable.map fromIntegral) (vec))

matrixToImg::Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Matrix Z ->  Image PixelRGB8
matrixToImg matrix = Image  (rows matrix `quot` 3) (cols matrix) (vectorToStorableVector (Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data.flatten(matrix)))
    where vectorToStorableVector = 
               Data.Vector.Storable.fromList . Prelude.map fromIntegral . Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data.toList
```